# Double question mark (??) is not recognized by Node.js v18

Tags: node.js, dependencies, version

```
/home/ec2-user/test-server/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/index.js:852
  requestId: output.headers["x-amzn-requestid"] ?? output.headers["x-amzn-request-id"] ?? output.headers["x-amz-request-id"],
                                                 ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1414:10)

Node.js v18.19.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

This is what I received when I tried to install a new dependency to my application.

I asked ChatGPT but it was confused as well since, based on what it told me, Node.js v18 is supposed to support `??` as a valid operator.

This happens when I tried to install a new `@aws-sdk/client-s3` package. May I know how to resolve it?

(This issue originally occurs at `@aws-sdk/client-s3` when I removed the node_modules and reinstall all dependencies. I then removed `^` mark before the version since I don't want it to be upgraded. Then this error re-occurs on one of its dependencies like this.)